# determine what secret handshake causes them to print the given lines ONE TIME ONLY

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals, sleep

So I need to find what causes this program to print out "I'm unlocked!" But when I run this algorithm, it prints out nothing.

I tried removing lines of code or adding sleep but no matter what I do it just prints out blank.

I am expected to print "I'm unlocked!"

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile int locked, t, c;

static void handler(int signo);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  locked = 1;
  t = c = 0;

  char * knock = getenv("KNOCK");
  if(knock == NULL || strcmp(knock, "KNOCK"))
  {
    return 1;
  }

  if(signal(SIGUSR1, handler) == SIG_ERR ||
     signal(SIGUSR2, handler) == SIG_ERR ||
     signal(SIGALRM, handler) == SIG_ERR)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: cannot register signal handlers\n", argv[0]);
    return 2;
  }

  while(locked)
  {
    pause();
  }

  puts("I'm unlocked!");

  return 0;
}

static void handler(int signo)
{
  switch(signo)
  {
    case SIGUSR1:
      if(c == 2)
      {
        t = alarm(3);
      }
      break;
    case SIGUSR2:
      c++;
      if(t == 1)
      {
        locked = 0;
      }
      break;
    case SIGALRM:
      t = 0;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to look at the return value of the `alarm()` function.  You're going to need to send the right sequence of signals with the right timing delays (not by hand, therefore; you'll probably need to use a script or program to do the job).  Each of `t`, `c` starts out as zero.  If the `alarm()` expires, you get sent back to the start with `t == 0`.  If `c` ever gets beyond 2, you're hosed (so don't send to many `SIGUSR2` signals).

Comment: How are you sending `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2` and `SIGALRM` to your program? Please show the command.

Comment: I just run the code using ./a.out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pause()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) function suspends the calling thread and returns when a signal that has a registered handler is invoked.

The loop then terminates when `pause()` returns *and* the `locked == 0`.

So the following signal sequence and timing will unlock:

```
SIGUSR2  // c = 1
SIGUSR2  // c = 2
SIGUSR1  // t = 0 (no scheduled alarm)
Delay two seconds
SIGUSR1  // t = 1 (alarm seconds remaining)
SIGUSR2  // locked = 0 (because t == 1)
```

The signals can be issued from a separate thread or process using the `kill()` function or from a shell script using the `kill` command.

Comment: So am I supposed to add that sequence within the while loop? B/c I tried and it didn't do anything

Comment: @HadealAl-safadi : No because the loop is suspended in the `pause()` - the signals must be injected from a separate thread or process.  For that `raise()` is actually the incorrect function, because it signals the calling thread; my error - I am no Linux expert - the point is the signal sequence and timing, not the method - I assumed you knew ;-).  From the command shell you can issue the signals using the `kill` command in a shell script.

Comment: Worth adding that the last `SIGUSR2` should be sent within 3 seconds of the previous `SIGUSR1` else `t` will be reset to `0` again.

Comment: So I tried doing that but it still didn't print out "I'm unlocked!".

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - no, it has to be sent immediately.  The timing is noted in the sequence. Where no delay is indicated, there is no delay - implicitly.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya add some debug output or use a debugger to see which steps in the sequence are taken ( instrument the signal handler).  The timing may be marginal, perhaps usleep(2500000).